# Error in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am very new to ios development, I am trying to add some values from `NSMutableDictionary` to `NSMutableArray`, when I run the code I get this error

> 2012-05-29 14:09:34.913 iShop[7464:f803] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e423d0 2012-05-29
>   14:09:34.915 iShop[7464:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e423d0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x13cb022 0x155ccd6 0x13cccbd 0x1331ed0 0x1331cb2 0x2bb7 0x13cce42 0x93b9df 0x139f94f 0x1302b43 0x1302424
>   0x1301d84 0x1301c9b 0x12b47d8 0x12b488a 0x15626 0x28bd 0x2825)
>   terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

below is my code:

```
-(void) getData:(NSData *) response {
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    //NSLog(@"%@", json);

    jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    jsonArray = [json objectForKey:@"Name"];

    NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray);

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/read_product_list.php"];
    dispatch_async(BgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getData:) 
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONObjectWithData` return an object of type `id`. depending on the structure of your received json data. 
The data recieved is eiher `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`. In your case I am guessing the top level object is of type `NSArray` which does not respond to `objectForKey`